# CSS - how to create circle pie canvas like this?

Tags: html, css, canvas

I really like this element,

[image: this element]

but how to create it? I am not sure what's the correct designation of the element...

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a clean solution: https://codepen.io/dgca/pen/jwZGqv

Answer (score 5):

This effect can be achieved by layering a couple `arc()`s:

```
// bright blue full circle
d.beginPath();
d.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
d.fillStyle = "#aaeeff";
d.fill();

// dark blue percentage circle
d.beginPath();
d.moveTo(50, 50);
d.arc(50, 50, 50, -0.5 * Math.PI, 0.78 * 2 * Math.PI - 0.5 * Math.PI, false);
d.fillStyle = "#00aaff";
d.fill();

// white inner filler
d.beginPath();
d.moveTo(50, 50);
d.arc(50, 50, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
d.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
d.fill();
```

and finally rendering the text:

```
d.moveTo(50, 50);
d.fillStyle = "#606060";
d.font = "12pt sans-serif";
d.fillText("78%", 36, 56);
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/j6NVg/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `<canvas>` element, I have chosen to construct the pie chart relying on CSS and JS entirely. The HTML markup is as follow:

```
<div class="pie" data-percent="78">
    <div class="left">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follow. The trick is to split the circle into two halves (the nested `.left` and `.right` elements). The halves will have their overflowing content hidden, and contain nested `<span>` that we will manipulate with JS for rotation later. Add vendor prefixes when appropriate :)

```
.pie {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.pie > div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pie span {
    background-color: #4a7298;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
    .pie .left span {
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
        transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    }
    .pie .right span {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
        transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    }
.pie:before,
.pie:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
    .pie:before {
        background-color: #fff;
        content: "";
        width: 75%;
        height: 75%;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .pie:after {
        content: attr(data-percent) "%";
        z-index: 200;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I have used the following with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".pie").each(function() {
        var percent = $(this).data("percent").slice(0,-1), // Removes '%'
            $left = $(this).find(".left span"),
            $right = $(this).find(".right span"),
            deg;

        if(percent<=50) {
            // Hide left
            $left.hide();

            // Adjust right
            deg = 180 - (percent/100*360)
            $right.css({
                "transform": "rotateZ(-"+deg+"deg)"
            });
        } else {
            // Adjust left
            deg = 180 - ((percent-50)/100*360)
            $left.css({
                "transform": "rotateZ(-"+deg+"deg)"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aw5Rf/7/

Comment: BTW, Your code needs some added browser-specific css to work in IE & FF.

Comment: Yup, definitely. I'm just using `-webkit-` as an example. I concur that perhaps drawing onto `<canvas>` is a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

Check the below links for more info (not an exact one.But you can get some idea).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myColor = ["#ECD078","#D95B43","#C02942","#542437","#53777A"];
var myData = [10,30,20,60,40];

function getTotal(){
var myTotal = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < myData.length; j++) {
myTotal += (typeof myData[j] == 'number') ? myData[j] : 0;
}
return myTotal;
}

function plotData() {
var canvas;
var ctx;
var lastend = 0;
var myTotal = getTotal();

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(200,150);
ctx.arc(200,150,150,lastend,lastend+
  (Math.PI*2*(myData[i]/myTotal)),false);
ctx.lineTo(200,150);
ctx.fill();
lastend += Math.PI*2*(myData[i]/myTotal);
}
}

plotData();

</script>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

For more info :[Graphing Data in the HTML5 Canvas Element Simple Pie Charts](http://html5.litten.com/graphing-data-in-the-html5-canvas-element-part-iv-simple-pie-charts/)

Another Link : [Pure CSS3 Pie Charts effect](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/751/Pure-CSS3-Pie-Charts-effect)

This is an online demo: http://jsbin.com/uFaSOwO/1/

Answer (score 3):

First of all what you need can be done exactly using [jQuery knob plugin](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/). Still interested in a CSS Solution, than here's what I have done

```
<div class="load_me"></div>

.load_me {
    margin: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shyvu/)

---

[Animating the Knob](http://jsfiddle.net/pMJmF/) <sup>[Credits](https://coderwall.com/p/tozq6g)</sup>

---

If you want to prevent the mouse alteration, you can simply add `readOnly`

```
$this.knob({
    readOnly: true
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pMJmF/1/)

Answer (score 3):

**[FIDDLE with ANIMATION](http://jsfiddle.net/Vppp9/3/)**

Here's my approach:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


/*
 * in canvas, 0 degrees angle is on the right edge of a circle,
 * while we want to start at the top edge of the circle.
 * We'll use this variable to compensate the difference.
 */
var relativeAngle = 270;

function drawCanvas() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 90, 90);
    //light blue circle
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#D8E8F7';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(45, 45, 35, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    //dark blue circle
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#66ADF4';
    ctx.beginPath();
    //notice the angle conversion from degrees to radians in the 5th argument
    ctx.arc(45, 45, 35, 1.5*Math.PI, ((angle + relativeAngle) / 180) * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    //text
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#666';
    ctx.font = 'bold 14px serif';
    // angle conversion to percentage value
    ctx.fillText(parseInt(100 * angle / 360).toString() + '%', 45, 45);
}

var angle;
function timeout() {
    angle = parseInt(360 * percent / 100);
    drawCanvas();

    if (angle > 360) {
        document.getElementById('run').disabled = false;
        percent = 0;
        return;
    }

    percent++;
    setTimeout(timeout, 10);
};

var percent = 0;

/* START the ANIMATION */
timeout();
```

At the bottom of the code you'll find a self evaluating function `timeout` which calls the `drawCanvas` function every 10 miliseconds and increments the blue circle angle. I hope everything is clear here. If not, feel free to ask!

**Enjoy it!**