# CSS3 simple donut chart

Tags: css, donut-chart

What I'm trying to do is create a simple donut chart. I'm currently using CSS(3) only but I don't know if it's possible without javascript.

What I have so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aBP5Q/

HTML:

```
<div class="donut-container" style="background: #9C0;">
    <div class="donut-inner">
        <div class="donut-label">HTML</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.donut-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.donut-inner {
    width: 134px;
    height: 134px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 65px;
    -moz-border-radius: 65px;
    border-radius: 65px;
}

.donut-label {
    line-height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I would like to display the green and blue colors as the precentage. So no green is 0% and full green (360 degrees) is 100%. Maybe even with a simple animation when the chart is loaded if its possible.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19606737/1542290 ? http://jsfiddle.net/pMJmF/1/

Comment: San:
The problem is I don't see any explaination/code. This way I don't know what exactly need for my simplistic donut chart. The example is nice and It's kinda what I'm looking for.

Mr. Alien:
I would like to use CSS only if possible. And the fiddle doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: jasonK - when you look at San's link use Firebug in FF, or Developer tools in Chrome/safari to see the CSS styling on the circles.

Comment: @user3037493
Yes I see it, the problem is that I don't know exactly what to use and what not. And is it true you need to make 2 rectangles for both halves in order to get the round progress effect?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

SVG for the win!

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}

.html .circle_animation {
    -webkit-animation: html 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: html 1s ease-out forwards;
}

.css .circle_animation {
    -webkit-animation: css 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: css 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes html {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 80; /* 50% would be 220 (half the initial value specified above) */
  }
}

@keyframes html {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 80;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes css {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 160;
  }
}

@keyframes css {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 160;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item html">
    <h2>HTML</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="item css">
    <h2>CSS</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#69aff4" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/4azpfk3r/)

---

Here is a version with background circles as requested in the comments:

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}

.html .circle_animation {
    -webkit-animation: html 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: html 1s ease-out forwards;
}

.css .circle_animation {
    -webkit-animation: css 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: css 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes html {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 80; /* 50% would be 220 (half the initial value specified above) */
  }
}

@keyframes html {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 80;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes css {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 160;
  }
}

@keyframes css {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 160;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item html">
    <h2>HTML</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#f2f2f2" fill="none"/>
      <circle class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="item css">
    <h2>CSS</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#f2f2f2" fill="none"/>
      <circle class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#69aff4" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

---

### How does it work?

`stroke-dasharray` is used to define the 'pattern' a dashed line uses ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)). By providing a single value you create a pattern with a dash of 440px and a space of 440px. (440px is roughly the circumference of the circle).

`stroke-dashoffset` effectively moves the starting point of the dash pattern ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset)).

A `dash-offset` of 220 (half of the `stroke-dasharray`) would produce a half-circle. 110 = quarter circle etc.

Comment: Looking good! Asked this question a pretty long time ago, but I'll accept it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: What I don't understand is how you determine the percentage of 100? I don't understand how you would set to say 75% or 50%.

Comment: @JeremyMiller  `stroke-dasharray` is used to define the 'pattern' a dashed line uses ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)). By providing a single value you create a pattern with a dash of 440px and a space of 440px. (440px is roughly the circumference of the circle). `stroke-dashoffset` effectively moves the starting point of the dash pattern ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset)). A `dash-offset` of 220 (half of the `stroke-dasharray`) would produce a half-circle. 110 = quarter circle etc.

Comment: Great example that works really well. However, it would be superb if there was an explanation into how it works. Cheers

Comment: Works great for me... except on Internet Explorer. Adding the "-ms-" prefix to the appropriate directives with no luck. Does anyone have a modification to this solution that will work under IE?

Comment: This example was not compatible with IE 9-11(win7) at least.  

Here is the best donut chart built with CSS+HTM 
I have found so far 

https://codepen.io/thelifemgmt/pen/Abyhj/

Comment: @Turnip this is fantastic! Is there a way to create a grey circular background line behind the animating colors?

Comment: If I understand this right, if you want to set it dynamic you have to change the key frames animation ? If that's the case this wouldn't be a good solution for something like a dashboard. Becase keyframes animation can't be changed inline...

Answer (score 10):

This answer is only possible because of Turnip's answer, but I made a few significant changes, and I'll explain how it works as well:

```css
.donutContainer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.donutContainer h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.donut {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  -webkit-animation: donut 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation: donut 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes donut {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  }
}

@keyframes donut {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="donutContainer">
    <h2>donut</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" style="stroke-dashoffset: 160;/* 160 of 440 */" class="donut" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#69aff4" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="donutContainer">
    <h2>donut 2</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" style="stroke-dashoffset: 220;/* 220 of 440 */" class="donut" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#FEC007" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Because the animation uses `from` instead of `to` to create the animation, browsers that don't support the animation will show the donut chart complete, instead of not at all. This also makes it possible to change the colored in portion of the donut chart with just inline CSS, and the same single CSS animation can work for *any number* of donut charts.

An explaination for the `svg` stuff:

`stroke-dasharray`: In this case, basically the total circumference of the circle.

`stroke-dashoffset`: the portion of the circle that is colored in. Zero (0) means all colored in (100%), 440 (or whatever you set the circumference) for none of it colored in (0%)

Attributes on the `circle` element:

`r`: radius of the circle

`cx`: "center X". the center of the circle (X coordinate from bottom left of `svg` element)

`cy`: "center Y". the center of the circle (Y coordinate from bottom left of `svg` element)

`stroke-width`: width of the stroke that will draw the donut

`stroke`: color of the donut

Answer (score 8):

i wrote this as a comment reply but it was too long :

hm... well, here is a fiddle for the second circle http://jsfiddle.net/LgtV2/ .... it has 3 pie parts. the first circle (100%) has 5 parts. you should play with the fiddle to learn how it works and so you can replicate it. i've never done this before and am just looking at link San posted, but it looks like this just uses multiple Divs with the css3 TRANSFORM to form the curves, and the pseudo selectors :before and :after for animations. The animations occur as the page itself is loading... EG: :before div1 loads it has a transform of 5, it loads and has a transform of 8, :after it loads it has a transform of 11.

code:

```
<div class="half_pie">
    <div class="half_part_pie_one half_bar_color half_percentage" data-percentage="35"></div>
    <div class="half_part_pie_two"></div>
    <div class="half_part_pie_three"></div> <span class="half_pie_icon iconfont-android"></span>

</div>

/*percentage STEPS (do not touch)*/
 .full_percentage[data-percentage="100"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="95"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(170deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(170deg);
    transform: rotate(170deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="90"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(155deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(155deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(155deg);
    transform: rotate(155deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="85"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(125deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(125deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(125deg);
    transform: rotate(125deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="80"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(110deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(110deg);
    transform: rotate(110deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="75"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="70"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(70deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(70deg);
    transform: rotate(70deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="65"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
    transform: rotate(55deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="60"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="55"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.full_percentage[data-percentage="50"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="50"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="45"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(170deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(170deg);
    transform: rotate(170deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="40"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(155deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(155deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(155deg);
    transform: rotate(155deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="35"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(125deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(125deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(125deg);
    transform: rotate(125deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="30"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(110deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(110deg);
    transform: rotate(110deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="25"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="20"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(70deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(70deg);
    transform: rotate(70deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="15"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
    transform: rotate(55deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="10"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="5"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.half_percentage[data-percentage="0"] {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
/*
 *
 * THE SECOND EXAMPLE
 * the second example for a max percentuage of 50% in this case
 *
 */

/*COLOR and STYLES (note: you can use gradients for the class full_bar_color)*/
 .half_bar_color {
    background: #3498db;
}
/*start chart pie code*/
 .half_pie {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
/*the background white circular color*/
 .half_pie:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
/*color white #fff to fix the rendering problem*/
 .half_pie:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff, inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff, inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #fff, inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
/*the icon*/
 span.half_pie_icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
/*ONE*/
 .half_part_pie_one {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    clip: rect(0px 100px 200px 0px);
}
/*TWO*/
 .half_part_pie_two {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    clip: rect(0px 100px 200px 0px);
}
/*THREE*/
 .half_part_pie_three {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    clip: rect(0px 200px 200px 100px);
    -webkit-animation: half_third 4s linear;
    -moz-animation: half_third 4s linear;
    -o-animation: half_third 4s linear;
    animation: half_third 4s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
/*THIRD animation*/
 @-webkit-keyframes half_third {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes half_third {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes half_third {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@keyframes half_third {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have modified a snippet I found on the web to make a simple doughnut chart using only HTML and CSS, here is the result:

```css
.block {
  margin: 25px 25px 0 0;
  background: #394264;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.donut-chart-block {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.donut-chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 100%
}

.donut-chart .center {
  background: #394264;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 70px;
}

.clip {
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#section1 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#section1 .item {
  background-color: #E64C65;
  transform: rotate(76deg);
}

#section2 {
  transform: rotate(76deg);
}

#section2 .item {
  background-color: #11A8AB;
  transform: rotate(140deg);
}

#section3 {
  transform: rotate(215deg);
}

#section3 .item {
  background-color: #4FC4F6;
  transform: rotate(113deg);
}

#section4 {
  transform: rotate(-32deg);
}

#section4 .item {
  background-color: #FCB150;
  transform: rotate(32deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="donut-chart-block block">
    <div class="donut-chart">
      <div id="section1" class="clip">
        <div class="item" data-rel="21"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="section2" class="clip">
        <div class="item" data-rel="39"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="section3" class="clip">
        <div class="item" data-rel="31"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="section4" class="clip">
        <div class="item" data-rel="9"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Decided to post it here as an alternative to the other answers. Cheers!

Comment: anyhting over 50deg get's confused!

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to create a donut chart animation (just plain css) and also need multiple colors for it then check the codepen example I have created.

http://codepen.io/hilar47/pen/RprXev

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="donut-chart-block block"> 
    <div class="donut-chart">
        <div id="part1" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
        <div id="part2" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
        <div id="part3" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
        <p class="center"></p>        
    </div>
```