# How to create this special loader using html5 css and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, pie-chart

the main problem is with the container of the percentage (the small circle), instead i can create the big one with easy pie chart plugin...

Any idea which i can follow please ??!

[image]

Comment: You should google it, maybe this one: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've took the code for the motion pie from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20529884/1542290)(please upvote his answer if you liked the pie)... And I've added mine for the Green Percentage circle, which I am hiding on load using `opacity: 0;` and showing after 3 seconds using `animation-delay` property and lastly I added `animation-fill-mode` property, so that your percentage `div` doesn't disappear..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LgtV2/19/)

```
.percent {
    -webkit-animation: show_percent 1s;
    -moz-animation: show_percent 1s;
    animation: show_percent 1s;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;

    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #00FF43;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 50;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
@-moz-keyframes show_percent {
    0% {
        display: none;
    }
    100% {
        display: block;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes show_percent {
    0% {
        display: none;
    }
    100% {
        display: block;
    }
}

@keyframes show_percent {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx Mr..... but the idea is that the Green Percentage circle should move while the blue bar moves, i mean it must stuck on the head of the bar, ust to make it clear for you, this is a preloader of a page :)

Comment: @kach well, you didn't described much in your question so just threw a demo :)